# baking displacement map from multires and applying it

Tags: baking, displacement

I cannot figure out how to bake displacement maps properly. Here is what I do:
I sculpt my mesh (UV unwrapped) with multires. I switch to blender internal, set my Multires preview to 1 subidiv and Render to the highest subdiv. I create a 32bit map and Bake with "Bake from multires" on. The resulting displacement map looks OK...

Applying the displacement map:
I remove the multires and apply a standartd subdiv modifier. I add a displacement modifier on top of that I set my map to be the map I baked in the previous step.Now if I play around with the strength and midpoint value I can get something close to the original sculpt but not quite the same.

Does anyone have a reliable, functioning workflow that eliminates the guesswork and produces clean results? Thank you!

Comment: what resolution is the displacement map? and you need alot of geometry for the displacement to be like the original, try 3 subdivison modifiers set to level 2 for example before the dispacement modifier

Comment: you could also achieve a result close to the orignal without alot of geometry by baking an AO map, and maybe also a normal map from the original sculpt and using them on the low poly version of your mesh.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I subdivide plenty of times before applying displacement.

Comment: As for AO, that's not my goal. I am trying to get the actual shape, volume and details of the mesh to represent my sculpt as closely as possible.